# Element positioning over scaled SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG image scaled to the size of the window. An element should be placed above the image relative to its size. As the size of the image changes in different browser windows, the positioning parameter should for example be something like 30% of the picture width from the left.

The problem is, that the browser adds a "padding" to maintain the aspect ratio. However this "padding" is not CSS and I have not found any way to access any data of the image rendering parameters.

Sounds complicated? Here is an external [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SamLowrie/amh7kes1/) or see the same code below (problem only shows in fullscreen mode). When resizing the browser window, the hashtag should stay at the same position above the image, however it moves arround, as padding is added on the sides of the image.

I could not find any way to access the svg properties to get something like the actual image origin (minus the padding) or the actual image size. Any solution with js, JQuery, css, etc. is fine.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

img#test {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div#test {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 31%;
  padding-top: 8%;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>

    <img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PScwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCcgeG1sbnM9J2h0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnJz4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNNjUsMjBhMTUsMTUsMCwxLDEsMTUsMTVoLTYwYTE1LDE1LDAsMSwxLDE1LTE1djYwYTE1LDE1LDAsMSwxLTE1LTE1aDYwYTE1LDE1LDAsMSwxLTE1LDE1eiIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjRDcwIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjgiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg=='
      id='test'>

    <div id='test'>#</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**Update:**

The answer from ccprog worked out great, but it gave me a bit of a headache to work out the correct aspect ratio. Here is an example for the correct settings, when the aspect ratio is not 1:1 (as in the example):

- Image-Resolution: 544 x 400 (width x height)
- Aspect-Ratio (width:height) : 544 / 400 = 1.36 => 1.36:1 => 136:100
- Aspect-Ratio (height:width) : 400 / 544 = 0.73529... => 74:100

The resulting media queries then look like this:

```css
media (min-aspect-ratio: 136/100) {
  .box {
     width: 136vh;
     height: 100vh;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 136/100) {
  .box {
     width: 100vw;
     height: 74vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this only concern this one image, or other well-known images? In short, do you _know_ the aspect ratio of the image(s) at all times?

Comment: The image is just an example, but I know the aspect ratio of the actual image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know the aspect ratio in advance, there are some CSS features you can combine.

- a `aspect-ratio` media query can decide whether the screen size is wider or smaller than the image aspect ratio
- depending on that, use `vh` units for wide screens and `vw` units for small ones to size a wrapping div with the same aspect ratio as the image
- use flex layout to position it in the middle of the screen, mimicking the behaviour of the SVG view box.

Then you can position your element in that outer div.

The following example uses your image with an aspect ratio of 1/1. For other values, you would have to replace that in the media query and adjust the width for wide screens and the height for small screens to get the right ratio.

I've given the wrapping div a blue border to show the effect.

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

img#test {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
.hash {
    position: absolute;
    left: 31%;
    top: 8%;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 50px;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
    .box {
        width: 100vh;
        height: 100vh; /* stays constant for all ratios */
    }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
    .box {
        width: 100vw; /* stays constant for all ratios */
        height: 100vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PScwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCcgeG1sbnM9J2h0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnJz4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNNjUsMjBhMTUsMTUsMCwxLDEsMTUsMTVoLTYwYTE1LDE1LDAsMSwxLDE1LTE1djYwYTE1LDE1LDAsMSwxLTE1LTE1aDYwYTE1LDE1LDAsMSwxLTE1LDE1eiIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjRDcwIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjgiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiLz4KPC9zdmc+Cg=='
  id='test'>
<div class="box">
    <div class="hash">#</div>
<div>
```

Comment: This works exactly like it is supposed to! Very nice solution without any js. Thanks!

Comment: After designing my page I realized that the above works great accross many browsers and platforms ... EXCEPT Chrome on Android (at least Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android 8.0). Chrome seems to incorporate the URL-Bar into the 100vh. As a result it seems that it displaces the center for the "display: flex; justify-content: center;" placement.